# SP Online and custom forms... not working as I expected

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, infopath, custom-list, custom-form

Background: SharePoint Online (O365) using SharePoint Designer 2013 and InfoPath Designer 2013.

Issue: we have a custom list to track Safety Incident Reporting in our 2 manufacturing facilities -- one in the US and 1 in Europe.

A) Any supervisory-level user can create a new incident which utilizes 8 basic columns in the list -- Who, What, When, etc.  This is a custom New form which opens in a modal dialog using some javascript. That works as expected... when they click the SUBMIT button, the modal box closes and the data is submitted to the custom list -- that works properly.

B) we also have 2 users (our environmental health & safety officers, one in each facility) who will edit the entries using the Edit form. They will add data to 35 additional columns which include root cause analysis, corrective actions, who was involved in the investigation, when the case was completed/closed, etc.

I used InfoPath to create a custom form called SIR-New (Safety Incident Reporting - New) with a view called SIR-New (which contains the shorter, 8-field submission form) and another view called SIR-Edit which contains all 43 fields. I save it and publish it to the custom SP list. When I go to SP Designer, I see that there are now 3 additional forms associated with the list -- newifs.aspx, editifs.aspx, and displayifs.aspx. I selected the newifs and editifs as the defaults, along with the standard DispForm.aspx.

I modified the javascript in the pop-up modal to call the newifs.aspx and it will pop-up the correct form and submit the data to the list properly. Sounds great, right? HOWEVER, when I'm viewing the display form and click on an entry, then select the Edit option (as if I were one of the safety officers), it opens the short form (newifs.aspx) and not the full form. I tried re-publishing it and the result was the opposite -- both the "new incident" link and the edit option opened the full 43 column form.

So what am I missing in this configuration? I assumed having a view for New would open that form and the Edit form would open when I choose the edit option. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Glenn

Comment: I knnow it's not an answer to your question, but going forward I would strongly advise to stop using Infopath in SharePoint online and switch to customizing your form with PowerApps (you need modern UI) or build PowerApps to facilitate your process. However, I agree your solution should work.

Comment: verify that you had enabled infopath forms for your O365 tenants before migration. Checkout my answer about enabling it at tenant level https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/244905/customizing-sharepoint-survey-form/244913#244913

Comment: DvG -- that option is enabled...